# Misaligned Carbon Rails on Brooks C13 Saddle not aligning to Seat Post Clamp

Tags: carbon, saddle, seatpost, alignment, torque

I have a [VNT Elements Seat Post] (https://shop.vannicholas.com/en/products/vnt-elements-accessories/VNT-Seatpost-Alloy-16-7mm-Setback/11326). This saddle has two bolts at the back and clamps onto the seat post on top. Van Nicholas also makes a titanium seat-post which clamps from the side and has special carbon saddle adapters for the titanium saddle. I assume that my saddle is compatible as no separate adapters are sold and, this is just a top-bottom clamp.

This seat post worked fine with my Montague Saddle with steel rails. I have now purchased a Brooks C13 Saddle with carbon rails and find that the rails are slightly closer together.

That said, I had a few questions,

1. My local bike shop told me that carbon saddles can only be mounted using clamps on the saddle. Is this true? Do I need to buy a different seat post?
2. If the top-bottom clamp is compatible, why are the rails so close together? Will it 'flex' into place when tightened? I don't have any experience with carbon and don't want to end up breaking the rails.

Here are some pictures.

Seat Post (Dis-assembled)

[image: Seat Post]

Seatpost Clamps on Montague Saddle - Good Alignment

[image: Seatpost Clamps on Montague Saddle - Good Alignment]

Clamp on Brooks C13 Saddle

[image: Clamp on Brooks C13 Saddle - 1]
[image: Clamp on Brooks C13 Saddle - 2]
[image: Clamp on Brooks C13 Saddle - 3]

Comment: Following this as it is an intriguing question.  Hopefully someone with shop or personal experience with this will share their knowledge and experiences.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote to Brooks and the Saddle Manufacturer. Brooks responded and said that their carbon saddles have a +/- 1mm deviation in their carbon rails due to the manufacturing process. They would flex into place when the seat post clamp is tightened.

I followed their instructions and well, it worked!